# Is it possible to shorten style imports within an angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

Following the docs on angular.io I have created a library. We have a styleguide that we want to use throughout the library & as such have a directory containing some shared styles & variables (e.g. colour palette).

Currently I am accessing these files from my component.scss files via relative imports. This is a pain as they are quite long & cumbersome. In a normal angular application you can shorten this using `stylePreprocessorOptions` within `angular.json` however this is not the case for the library config as the field is not allowed!

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/component-library/ng-package.json"
            // usually you could define stylePreprocessorOptions here!
          }
    }
}
```

I came across an alternative `styleIncludePaths` - https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/HEAD/docs/style-include-paths.md

But this is unfortunately not doing what I expected... probably through my own misunderstanding! To clarify it lets me define this option within my ng-package.json however the import pathway is unable to resolve correctly within my component.scss

My ideal goal would be to change the import pathway from something like

`@import '../../../../styles/theme'`

to

`@import 'theme'`

I am probably going about this the wrong way for a library but struggling to find examples of how this can be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated & if you need any more info please ask!

Thanks